# How to fix wrong system time and date?

Tags: 12.10, time, date

I just ran a clean install of 12.10 on my sys76 laptop.

Time and date reads: `19:36 31 december 1969`, even though it is: `13:29 07 november 2012`.

I have it set for my location and it won't change manually, even tried in the command line with `tz`.

I think it is messing up the security certificates over the Internet cause I cannot change PPA over command line and going to Launchpad brings up the certificates page in Firefox.

Is this some known bug or is there a fix for it?

Comment: Dude... your computer is fine - it is 1969. Woodstock is apparently going to be pretty good this year...

Comment: To everyone with a later release:     

Quote: "Since Ubuntu 16.04 timedatectl / timesyncd (which are part of systemd) replace most of ntpdate / ntp. "

From:   https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp

Comment: You may also need to set your timezone: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-check-and-set-timezone-in-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 89):

Try:

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Yes, it would certainly mess with the SSL certificates, because they would be future-dated.

I doubt it's a bug in Ubuntu. Your CMOS clock in the BIOS must have been set to that somehow.

Comment: 18 Apr 15:06:04 ntpdate[29230]: no server suitable for synchronization found

Comment: after installing >> sudo apt-get install ntp>> `18 Apr 15:07:03 ntpdate[30070]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting`

Comment: That's fine for a one-off fix, but you'll still have system drift and get off again.  You really want to install `ntp` to get the ntpd deamon running (At that point `ntpdate` will then give the error _"the NTP socket is in use, exiting"_ which is what you want, because ntpd is taking care of keeping the clock in sync)

Comment: maybe need: `sudo apt-get install ntpdate` beforehand

Answer (score 37):

Just install ntp server:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

It will automatically keep your clock synchronized.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me on Ubuntu 13.10. No idea why. (Problem was that the clock was off by one hour after daylight saving time/summer time took effect.)

Comment: I installed ntp however my time is still ahead by 5 minutes. How long does it take to update the time or do I need to run any command after? Thanks

Comment: Mine took a few minutes to run, then it finally set the clock correctly

Comment: well this doesn't help if apt-get fails because of gpg errors that come from the system time being wrong

Comment: Installing this package removes another one `systemd-timesyncd`. Is it OK to do it?

Answer (score 22):

Install ntp and ntpdate executing the following commands-

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
```

Then, execute

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

This works for me.

Comment: Pretty sure that if you do it in that order, that `ntpdate` will give the error "_the NTP socket is in use, exiting_" because the ntp package should have started `ntpd` which grabs the socket.

Comment: Don't you only need ntp?

Comment: @Randall is correct, however it still updates the time.  Don't know if there are any other side effects though.

Answer (score 5):

After installing 12.10 I had the same problem as well. Somehow the new installation set the BIOS clock to the year 2070 !! After this, Ubuntu wasn't able to set a different date both by ntp, manually, even using the **date** command.

Setting the right date in the BIOS settings solved the problem.

Comment: how did you set the right date in the BIOS?

Answer (score 3):

This works for Ubuntu 16.04

1. Stop the ntp service
2. Run ntpdate command to fetch date/time from ntp.ubuntu.com

   ```
   systemctl stop ntp
   sudo ntpdate -s ntp.ubuntu.com
   ```

P.S: Make sure ntp is installed, if not just do

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Answer (score 3):

find your timezone:

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

and then set your timezone based on your choice:

```
timedatectl set-timezone <YOUR_TIME_ZONE>
```

Comment: This was my issue,  System was in wrong time zone

Answer (score 2):

I changed the hardware clock. Use the [**hwclock**](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock) command to fix it:

```
sudo ntpdate <my.ntp.server>
sudo hwclock -w
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this package to get the clock of your server right:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude install ntp
```

Then define your time zone (the one where your server is located):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Details:

https://safaetulahasan.medium.com/set-time-of-your-server-right-7145899166a4